# Typescript Utils class return React Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am doing a typescript React project and am attempting writing some utility classes.  I am having issues returning a React component this way though and not sure what would I should be doing/what is best practice.  I am getting the "refers to a value, but is being used as a type here." error unless I use a tsx file, in which case it can't be properly imported.  Also worth noting throwing a @ts-ignore alleviates that error but then errors as "Unterminated regular expression literal"

Edit: this is error with `<SomeIcon />` etc.

Here is my BoxUtils.ts

```
export abstract class BoxUtils {
    public static getIconForStatus(box: BoxModel): Icon | null {
        switch(box.status) {
            case 'StatusOne':
                return <SomeIcon />;
            case 'StatusTwo':
                return <SomeOtherIcon />;
            case 'StatusThree':
                return <YetAnotherIcon />;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a fragment of where I would use the util:
`<div>{BoxUtils.getIconForStatus(row)}</div>`

Comment: Am I correct in guessing that you are getting the error on the line including the React components?

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is erroring on <SomeIcon /> etc.

Comment: JSX syntax (`<XYZ />`) does not work in TS files, only TSX. You'll need to change the file extension and figure out the import problem

Comment: If you will share reproducable example in codesandbox it will increase your chances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you've included in the following lines are JSX syntax, meaning that they contain ES6 components that aren't build into the interpreter of the Typescript language.

```
return <SomeIcon />;
return <SomeOtherIcon />;
return <YetAnotherIcon />;
```

However you can include these syntax capabilities by marking the file as `.tsx` rather than `.ts`. If you were only including typescript functions or types, you could use just the `.ts` file extension.

Comment: As noted by @Clashsoft and shn the file needs to be .tsx and the import fixed.  My syntax was incorrect from the original .ts extension.  I also needed to add export default to my (now) tsx class.

Before: import { BoxUtils } from '../utils/BoxUtils';
After: import BoxUtils from '../utils/BoxUtils';